# How to avoid ffmpeg encode Annex-B h264 stream ouput when hardware encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

I use wireshark to analysis the h264 ouput of ffmpeg encoding by "h264_qsv",its very strange which contains a lot of PPS,seems like its Annex-B. And Annex-B cannot decode when playing on some machine.
Is there a way to avoid encoding make the h264 stream like Annex-B?

```
    pH264Codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("h264_qsv");
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGolI.png)

Answer (score 0):

No, hardware encoders always produce annex b, you will need to post process it to convert to another format.